# Temperature required for ionisation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, temperature

What is the temperature required for an atom of helium so that atom can have enough energy to ionise? No more info is given.

Comment: Hint: what is the electrostatic potential of the system?

Comment: I am sure it must have something to do with ionisation energy which we can calculate easily.I am not sure how to connect it with temperature.

Comment: Also note you need to make assumption that the temperature is high enough so that $E\approx kT$.

Comment: Now I get it.What would happen if temperature is not high enough so that relation is not good?

Comment: Is this a volume of helium gas or a single atom? It's very difficult to talk about the temperature of a single atom. With an volume of gas we can talk about the average kinetic energy and its relationship to the temperature.

Comment: It is single atom.It is supposed to be solved with regards to formulas Bohr and others derived.I mean formulas like Bohr radius, velocity on n orbital etc..

Answer (score 2):

You need to know the electron density as well as the ionization energy X.  You might think you'd get ionization when kT ~ X, but actually you tend to get ionization when kT << X.  For example, you may have heard that the era of recombination of the universe was when T ~ 3000 K, but that means kT is about 1/60 of the X for hydrogen.

The reason for this has to do with what is known as the "statistical weight of the continuum,"  which basically means, how many free states are available to the ionized electron.  When bound, the electron has only the ground state (let's ignore the two spin states, as they are there for free electrons also so are not playing any important role), but when ionized, it has access to a truly a vast number of free states.  So that strongly favors that the electron should be ionized, so when T ~ 3000 K, the probability of a transition from the ground state to a single one of the ionized states is extremely tiny, since kT/X is very small, but there are so many such states, the transitions do happen.  The number of states available to the electron is inversely proportional to the electron density.